# React-native create an unsigned apk from app that hasn't run once in an android device/emulator

Tags: jenkins, react-native

So when I run this command to create an unsigned apk:

`react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug`

The above command works **if and and only if** I have run before the `react-native run-android` command. Which I think creates some directories `/bundle`that allows the first command to run.

Since we are trying to set up a CI server with Jenkins and we need to generate an unsigned apk. Is there anyway to generate an unsigned apk from repository code without having the default dir generate when you run the `react-native run-android` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with command

```
$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

For debug app use `assembleDebug`

For more about generate apk, you can check react native doc on
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#generating-the-release-apk